# Finding density of $X$ when it has characteristic function $\varphi(t)=(1+|t|)e^{-|t|}$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, density-function, characteristic-functions

[image]
[image]

I did the second step for this question but I can not fix it, and How can I fix this integral

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Can you use MathJax for to write the problem? Also, It's important you show your attempts fot to solve this problem.

Comment: Your expression has $\phi(t)$ translated into the expression for $\phi(x)$.  Correct it first!

Comment: You simply had copied it wrong!

Comment: Please typeset using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $\phi(t)$ is an even function of $t$ $f_x(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty cos(tx)(1+t)e^{-t}dt=\frac{1}{\pi}(\frac{1}{1+x^2}+\frac{1-x^2}{(1+x^2)^2})=\frac{2}{\pi(1+x^2)^2}$

Comment: Note:  The integrals are from Gradshteyn and Ryzhzik.  I hope I got them right.